# How to create files named aa, ab, ac, ... zz

Tags: linux

How can I create files named as the sequence `aa`, `ab`, `ac`, ... `zz`?

I'm trying to do some incorrect stuff like:

```bash
touch {\[a-z\]..\[a-z\]}[[text]
```

... or this:

```bash
touch [aa-zz].txt
```

... and of course, it doesn't work.

I am just new to Linux.

Comment: Can you please provide more information about what you're trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the square brackets. As `touch` accepts multiple files in a single commandline, you can do so like this:

```
$ touch {a..z}{a..z}.txt
$ ls|wc -l
     676
```

If you need further manipulation, you can do so in a for loop, like so:

```
$ for letters in {a..z}{a..z}; do echo "$letters"; done
```

or even with a double-loop:

```
$ for first_letter in {a..z}; do
>     for second_letter in {a..z}; do
>         echo "Filename: ${first_letter}${second_letter}.txt"
>     done
> done
```

Note that with two adjacent variables the use of curly brackets like `${variable}` is sometimes required, but in this case while not needed, it does make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for i in {a..z}{a..z}; do 
    touch $i; 
done
```

Where `{a..z}{a..z}` will start at `aa` and end with `zz`, `touch` creates the file

Comment: That will also create files like `ab`, `ac`, and so on. I guess that is not what OP wants.

Comment: Why not? `ac` is mentioned in the OP?

Comment: My bad. I completely missed that first line.